# bootstrap 4 не выравнивается меню

Tags: css, bootstrap4

Есть меню,но при этом по бокам меню имеются отступы. я пытался выровнять блоки по ширине,но отступы в сером цвете никуда не уходят. красной линией показал их

```html
<nav class="navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
  <div class="d-md-none">  <a class="navbar-brand d-xm-block" href="#">Hidden brand</a></div>

<div class="col">

<a href="сказка" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>сказка</span>  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="color:#000;font-size:10px;">3</span></a>

<a href="история" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><span>история</span>  <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill" style="color:#000;font-size:10px;">5</span></a>

</div></div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `<div class="col">` добавляет `padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px;`

Решений для вашей проблемы очень много...

Допишите новый класс который будет убирать `padding`, или удалите `class="col"` , но придется дописать `width:100%`